# Generate bills from two tables using mysql query

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have a table below in database which is as following,

**menugroups** :

```
+----Name---+--PrintOdr-+
+-----------+-----------+
|Starters   |1          |
|Deserts    |2          |
|Soups      |3          |
+-----------+-----------+
```

And another table as following,

**Orders**

```
+----ID-----+---Name----+--MenuGrp--+TableNo+
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|1          |Sandwich   |Starters   |1      |
|"space"    |Cheese     |Starters   |1      |
|2          |Chips      |Starters   |1      |
|3          |Brownie    |Deserts    |1      |
|"space"    |IceCream   |Deserts    |1      |
|1          |Sandwich   |Starters   |1      |
|2          |Chips      |Starters   |1      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Now I want the bill to be generated as,

**tablenos** :

```
+----Name---+--Qty--+
+-----------+-------+
|Sandwich   |1      | 
|Cheese     |1      |
|Chips      |2      |
|Sandwich   |1      |
|Brownie    |1      |
|Icecream   |1      |
+-----------+-------+
```

`PrintOdr` in `menugroups` gives the order in which the Items Ordered are to be printed.
So according to `menugroups` defined above Starters should be printed first and then Deserts and then Soups. `menugroups` can also have same `PrintOdr` indicating they can be printed in any order. In `orders` items whose `ID="Space" (means " ")` they are toppings added to the above item. So now when bill is to be generated if item doesn't have any toppings then they can be added together as in the case above with chips. But if items have toppings then they shouldn't be added with similar items ordered as in the case of Sandwich.

So please provide me help to generate a query for the same.

Comment: I don't understand - what's "space" (no silly answers)

Comment: And consider providing proper DDLs

Comment: this one looks tricky with the toppings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the topping it's so tricky, a lot of playing around with variables but here's a query that gives you what you want. Basically I play around with variables to generate different IDs if an item hasToppings.

```
SELECT IF(IsTopping, CONCAT("+",t3.Name),t3.Name) as DisplayName,
       Count(*) as Qty,
       IF(HasTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,GeneratedId),
        IF(isTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,GeneratedId),CONCAT(t3.Name,ID))) as newName

FROM
(
SELECT *,IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
                 (select *,IF (@prevNewId2 != newId,@generatedID2:=@generatedID2 + 1,@generatedID2) as generatedID,
         @prevNewId2 := NewId
from
(select *,IF (ID = ' ',@prevID2,ID) as newID,
         IF (ID != ' ',@prevID2 := ID,@prevID2),
         IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping

from orders,(SELECT @prevID2 := 0)var)o,(SELECT @prevNewId2:=0,@generatedID2 := 1000)var
 )t2
WHERE t2.generatedID = t1.generatedID
  AND t2.isTopping = 1
                 ) AND isTopping = 0,1,0) as hasTopping
FROM
(select *,IF (@prevNewId != newId,@generatedID:=@generatedID + 1,@generatedID) as generatedID,
         @prevNewId := NewId
from
(select *,IF (ID = ' ',@prevID,ID) as newID,
         IF (ID != ' ',@prevID := ID,@prevID),
         IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping      
from orders,(SELECT @prevID := 0)var)o,(SELECT @prevNewId:=0,@generatedID := 1000)var
 )t1

)t3 INNER JOIN menugroups mg ON mg.Name = t3.MenuGrp
GROUP BY DisplayName,NewName
ORDER BY mg.PrintOdr,t3.generatedID,t3.isTopping
```

please see [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcdef/17/0), you can just ignore the `newname` column it's only used for grouping, but `displayname` and `qty` column gives you what you want.
You might have to add `WHERE TableNo = 1` to whenever there's a select from `orders` if you have multiple TableNo(s).

second version query to solve issue where 1 sandwich is with topping right after another sandwich without topping.

```
SELECT IF(IsTopping, CONCAT("+",t3.Name),t3.Name) as DisplayName,
 Count(*) as Qty,
 IF(HasTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,GeneratedId),
 IF(isTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,GeneratedId),CONCAT(t3.Name,ID))) as newName

FROM
(
SELECT *,IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
 (select *,IF (@prevNewId2 != newId,@generatedID2:=@generatedID2 + 1,@generatedID2) as generatedID,
 @prevNewId2 := NewId
from
(select *,IF (ID = ' ',@prevID2,@newId2:=@newId2+1) as newID,
 IF (ID != ' ',@prevID2 := @newId2,@prevID2),
 IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping 
from orders,(SELECT @prevID2 := 0,@newId2:=0)var
)o,(SELECT @prevNewId2:=0,@generatedID2 := 1000)var
 )t2
WHERE t2.generatedID = t1.generatedID
 AND t2.isTopping = 1
 ) AND isTopping = 0,1,0) as hasTopping
FROM
(select *,IF (@prevNewId != newId,@generatedID:=@generatedID + 1,@generatedID) as generatedID,
 @prevNewId := NewId
from
(select *,IF (ID = ' ',@prevID,@newId:=@newId+1) as newID,
 IF (ID != ' ',@prevID := @newId,@prevID),
 IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping 
from orders,(SELECT @prevID := 0,@newId:=0)var

)o,(SELECT @prevNewId:=0,@generatedID := 1000)var
 )t1

)t3 INNER JOIN menugroups mg ON mg.Name = t3.MenuGrp
GROUP BY DisplayName,NewName
ORDER BY mg.PrintOdr,t3.generatedID,t3.isTopping;
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e796c/1/0)

here's a shorter version that works (also with rate and price)

```
SELECT IF(IsTopping, CONCAT("+",t3.Name),t3.Name) as DisplayName,
 Count(*) as Qty,
 t3.rate,t3.rate * Count(*) as price,
 IF(HasTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,newId),
 IF(isTopping,CONCAT(t3.Name,newId),CONCAT(t3.Name,ID))) as newName
FROM
(SELECT *,IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
                       (select *,IF (ID = ' ',@newId2,@newId2:=@newId2+1) as newID,
                                 IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping 
                        from orders,(SELECT @newId2:=1000)var
                       )t2
                      WHERE t2.newId = t1.newId
                      AND t2.isTopping = 1
                      ) AND isTopping = 0,1,0
             ) as hasTopping
 FROM (select *,IF (ID = ' ',@newId,@newId:=@newId+1) as newID,
                IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping 
       from orders,(SELECT @newId:=1000)var
       )t1
)t3 INNER JOIN menugroups mg ON mg.Name = t3.MenuGrp
GROUP BY DisplayName,NewName,rate
ORDER BY mg.PrintOdr,t3.newId,t3.isTopping;
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4dbf/12/0)

Comment: Thank you Tin for the above query. I just want to know as its a very big query how do i use it in vb6 as it does not fit in 1 line. We use "_" i guess but i get some end of statement error.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with VB6 anymore.

Comment: make you have a space at end of each line before closing quote `" _` because if not it'll get all stringed together and having incorrect syntax.

Comment: recset.open "SELECT IF(IsTopping, CONCAT(" + ",t3.ItemName),t3.ItemName) as DisplayName,Count(*) as Qty,IF(HasTopping,CONCAT(t3.ItemName,GeneratedId),IF(isTopping,CONCAT(t3.ItemName,GeneratedId),CONCAT(t3.ItemName,ID))) as newName" _

Comment: & "from(SELECT *,IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM(select *,IF (@prevNewId2 != newId,@generatedID2:=@generatedID2 + 1,@generatedID2) as generatedID, @prevNewId2 := NewId from (select *,IF (ID = ' ',@prevID2,ID) as newID,IF (ID != ' ',@prevID2 := ID,@prevID2), IF (ID = ' ',1,0) as isTopping" _

Comment: so i hav added " _ and & in your query but i get recset.State=0 on running it though i have records

Comment: you're missing a space between `newName` and `"` so when you go to the next line it thinks it's `newNamefrom` which is incorrect syntax. that's why you need a space before closing the quote `"`. Either add a space before the closing `"` or add a space after `& "` so that there's a space in between your SQL terms.

Comment: Still the same. My query looks like this: "select... " _ (next line) & ".......",adoconn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic. It does not throw any syntax error but recset.State=0

Comment: is it giving you errors? what does recset.State=0 mean? i am not familiar with VB.

Comment: why don't you try setting a string to hold the query first then try outputing that string and cut and paste that string into your query browser and see if it returns anything. and then recset.open thatstring. i don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: I ran the query and it gave me proper categorization according to PrintOdr. But it does not add the qtys of same Items if no toppings are added on them.

Comment: Hey i am sorry your query runs properly. It gives me perfect output when i have one sandwich with cheese and other without cheese but seperated by other items in between. If the same are placed one below the other meaning sandwich and then sandwich+cheese then it adds up the sandwich(2)+cheese.

Comment: there i updated my answer with a second version query at the bottom try that one.

Comment: Perfect Tin thanks a lot. One last thing i just want to display the rate and price as well. Rate is the actual money of each item and price means qty+actualmoney. Rate and Price fields are there in orders table.

Comment: don't you mean qty x actualmoney? you should be able to just add that to the select and the group by field.

Comment: @user3092228 i updated my answer to have a **shorter version** that works and it also returns `rate` and `price`, try using that one

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it would be better related if you place the menugroup id in the column MenuGrp of orders for now you can join on tables on the basis of names and MenuGrps

```
SELECT 
  o.`name`,
  COUNT(o.`name`) AS qty 
FROM
  orders o 
  JOIN menugroups m 
    ON (m.`name` = o.MenuGrp) 
GROUP BY o.`name` 
ORDER BY m.PrintOdr ASC
```